# Does PIL create artifacting on the bottom edge of the image when you thumbnail() then crop()? If so, what is your workaround?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging

When I call PIL to thumbnail() an image, and then crop(), I get artifacting on the last row of pixels -- they're either mostly black with specks of intense color, or what seems to be a not-resized area of the image ( ie, that line of pixels is at the original resolution and did not scale down with the rest )

This does not seem to happen on a thumbnail() without a crop.
This happens whether or not I call a load() on the cropped image either.

To get around this visually, i've been thumbnailing to a 1pixel larger image, and then cropping to the same size.  That seems to work.  It's kind of a dirty hack though.  I'm wondering if there's a proper fix.

Comment: Does using `resize` instead fix it? I've always had quality problems with `thumbnail`.

Comment: score!

yeah, that totally fixes the issues.  now the image looks right!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this happens to me also.  This was a learning exercise for me because I have never cropped or created thumbnails using the PIL...

### thumbnail(size,filter=None)

Replaces the original image, in place, with a new image of the given size (p. 2). The optional
filter argument works in the same way as in the .resize() method.
The aspect ratio (height : width) is preserved by this operation. The resulting image will be as large
as possible while still fitting within the given size. **For example, if image im has size (400,150), its
size after im.thumbnail((40,40)) will be (40,15)**.

So what is happening is

1. You use thumbnail which maintains
   the aspect
2. You're expecting the
   image to be 40 x 40
3. You're cropping beyond the actual size of the thumbnail
4. A black strip most likely on the bottom due to cropping beyond the size

Code I wrote to repeat the issue:

```
def croptest(file, width, height):
    import Image as pil
    import os

    max_width = width
    max_height = height
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(file)

    img = pil.open(file)
    img.thumbnail((max_width, max_height), pil.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(file + ".thumb.jpeg", 'JPEG')
    croppedImage = img.crop((10, 10, 40, 40))
    croppedImage.save(file + ".croppedthumb.jpeg", 'JPEG')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   croptest("Desktop.bmp", 50, 50)
```

Desktop.thumb.jpeg was 50 x 37 whereas Desktop.croppedthumb.jpeg was 30 x 30 so I had a 3 pixel high black line across the bottom.

Your solution would be either to crop inside the actual size of the thumbnail or figure out how to create a thumbnail ignoring the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks @manifest ; my code already defends against situations like yours and resized to the exact size of the crop.  The issue wasn't with a black line, but that there was an artifacted line that was either black with specks of color or did not seem to be resized.

Comment: Well I'm going from a 1600 x 1200 to 50 x 37 thumbnail, than I changed my crop above to have the "lower" 37.  Black line is gone and no artifacts.  I'm not sure what your issue might be, but good luck!

Comment: here's a pastebin of the code that i use:

http://pastebin.com/T3zMemTv

thanks to @bobince , i'll refactor the thumbnail() to resize() for all situations -- not just the crop methods.

feel free to use this code it if it helps you at all.